# Is there an online hyphenation tool?

Tags: resources, словарь, software

The question [How do I split a word into syllables?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-do-i-split-a-word-into-syllables) and its answers are helpful if one speaks Russian. Unfortunately I do not speak Russian but need to hyphenate 'Churyumov-Gerasimenko' (there must be other possibilities besides the existing hyphen). Is there some online hyphenation tool or dictionary for Russian which provides hyphenation and has an English GUI?

Comment: For your specific case, you can hyphenate it as _Chu-ryu-mov-Ge-ra-si-men-ko_ (or, in Cyrillic, _Чу-рю-мов-Ге-ра-си-мен-ко_). Unfortunately, I can't help with an online tool for you.  I do use MS Office Proofing Tools (Russian), which has pretty good hyphenation support.  LibreOffice, which I use on my linux machine also supports hyphenating Russian text.

Comment: @AleksG: Thanks, that solved my problem. I use neither MS Office Proofing Tools nor LibreOffice. If I would be allowed to, I would upvote your comment, but my reputation on russian.stackexchange.com is too low to do that.

Comment: OK, got the reputation now, upvoted your comment. Thanks again! It was also very helpful to have it in Cyrillic, because the on-line tool given in the accepted answer needs Cyrillic input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a multilingual hyphenation tool online here: [ushuaia•pl online hyphenation tool](http://www.ushuaia.pl/hyphen/?ln=en)

It is based on the same hyphenation engine that is used in OpenOffice and can auto-hyphenate Russian words, but unfortunately can only accept words written in Cyrillic (which in your case would be Чурюмов-Герасименко).

Comment: Nice link! However this tool knows that breaking the line after "Чурюмов-Ге-" looks ugly, so it doesn't show this option, though "ге" is valid syllable.

Comment: @Artemix Ah, good observation. I didn't notice that. In this specific case, if you just wanted to break the word into syllables you could of course delete the original dash and replace it with a space, i.e. "Чурюмов Герасименко". Then you will get the expected output broken into syllables: `чу•рю•мов ге•ра•си•мен•ко`

Comment: +1 and accepted, thanks! Transcription to Cyrillic is an acceptable effort, and the tool hyphenates not only Russian but Assamese, Basque, Belarusian, Bulgarian, Bengali, Catalan, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, English, Esperanto, Estonian, Faroese, Finnish, French, Galician, German, Greek, Greek (ancient), Greek (polytonic), Gujarati, Hindi, Hungarian, Icelandic, Indonesian, Interlingua, Irish, Italian, Kannada, Kurdish (Kurmanji), Latin, Latvian, Lithuanian, Malayalam, Māori, Marathi, Mongolian, Norwegian, Oriya, Panjabi, Polish, Portuguese, (to be continued)...

Comment: ...(continuation) Romanian, Sanskrit, Serbian (cyrillic), Serbian (latin), Slovak, Slovenian, Spanish, Swedish, Tamil, Telugu, Turkmen, Ukrainian, Upper Sorbian, Welsh!